# Create a function that takes in a list of tuples, where each tuple has two elements

Tags: pythonanywhere

The first element is a customer name (string) and the second element is that customer's total bill for the month (float). The function's purpose is to process this list, creating "billing emails" for each customer using the following template:

```
'Dear {},\n\nYou owe ACME Corp ${:.2f}.\n\nBest,\nACME Corp'
```

The function should return a list of these generated emails.It should be named "generate_billing_emails". The input should be called "customer_data"

```
test_data = [("Wile E Coyote", 345.67), ("Bugs Bunny", 25.49), ("Foghorn Leghorn", 68.00), ("Tweety", 5.99)]

billing_emails = generate_billing_email(test_data)

for billing_email in billing_emails:        
    print("{}".format( billing_email ))
    print("\n\n--------")
```

My Code so far :

```
def generate_billing_email(test_data):
    billing_emails = 'Dear {},\n\nYou owe ACME Corp ${:.2f}.\n\nBest,\nACME Corp'
    return billing_emails
```

Comment: Your instructor must have mentioned in class something about `for` loops and the string `format` method.

Comment: He did but im confused since there is a float and string

Comment: @RayHarlequin In some languages, it is important to distinguish between floats and strings.  Python is _not_ one of those languages.  The only place in this problem where it _might_ matter is the format string and your instructor has already provided you with a good one that uses `{:,.2f}` to format the float nicely.

Comment: So is the function right? i also added:customer_data = 0
    for item in [("Wile E Coyote", 345.67), ("Bugs Bunny", 25.49), ("Foghorn Leghorn", 68.00), ("Tweety", 5.99)]:
        customer_data = customer_data + 1

Comment: I'm sorry if i sound stupid but im very new to python. first time coding

Comment: I'm actually using python anywhere since i dont have pycharm available at home

Comment: im new to this site too ill change the tag

Comment: @Mr.goosberry can you help me with the question or not?

Comment: I haven't used python-anywhere but one of the nice things about python is that it has an interactive interpreter.  You can type in individual commands and see what happens.  So, try some commands, such as a string `format`, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

To do what your trying to do, you must loop though your data using a for-loop. And also, you can just use the format function by passing in the arguments. There is no need to tell Python if your using a float, string, integer, etc...

Here's how I would re-write your function:

```
def generate_billing_email(test_data):
    emails = []
    for tupe in test_data:
        emails.append("'Dear {0},\n\nYou owe ACME Corp ${1}.\n\nBest,\nACME Corp'".format(tupe[0], tupe[1]))
    return emails
```